# Tabularx landscape on several pages

Tags: tabularx, landscape

I would like to reverse the direction of my table, but I don't know how to do that. I would like to make a rotation of 180° but the command rotate doesn't work.

How can I do this ?
Attached there are the code and two pictures of the table.
Thanks in advance for your help

[image]
[image]

```
    \begin{landscape}

\vspace{-15mm}
\hspace{-10mm}

\begin{small}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\label{SNNvergleich}
\begin{tabularx}{246mm}{@{\,}>{\setlength\hsize{.66\hsize}}Y >{\setlength\hsize{1.49\hsize}}X  >{\setlength\hsize{1.56\hsize}}X  >{\setlength\hsize{1.56\hsize}}X  >{\setlength\hsize{0.34\hsize}}X  >{\setlength\hsize{0.42\hsize}}X @{\,}}
\caption{Example of an table}\\

    \toprule
            \textbf{Verfahren} & \textbf{Wirkungsweise} & \textbf{Vorteil}  & \textbf{Nachteil}    & \textbf{relative Kosten \cite{\ship}}    & \textbf{Festigkeits\-steigernder Faktor}    \\[18pt]
    \toprule%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \textbf{Beschleifen} &%Wirkung
                                                                                    Verbesserung der Nahtgeometrie
                                                                            &%Vorteil
                                                                             \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item   Einfache Durchführung
                                                                            \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                            &%Nachteil
                                                                                \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item Erforderung eines guten Zugänglichkeits des \NU{}s        \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005}
                                                                                    \item großer Zeitaufwand \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005, \ship}
                                                                                    \item großen Kosten \cite{\ship}
                                                                                \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                     &%Kosten
                                                                                    6 -- 18
                                                                            &%Faktor

                                                                            \\[18pt]

    \midrule%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
        \textbf{\WIGA} &%Wirkung
                                                                                    Verbesserung der Nahtgeometrie
                                                                            &%Vorteil
                                                                                \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item standardmäßige Umsetzung  \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005}
                                                                                    \item Ausrüstung schon vorhanden, falls vorherige Einsetzung des WIG-Schweißens
                                                                                    \item mögliche Automatisierung \cite{\ship}
                                                                                \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                            &%Nachteil
                                                                                \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item fast ausschließlich in Wannenlage (schlechte Zugänglichkeit) \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005}
                                                                                    \item hohe Kosten wegen qualifizierte Arbeitskräfte \cite{\ship}
                                                                                    \item Vorbereitung der \NB: Entfernen der ganzen Schmutz erforderlich \cite{\ship, \IIWPWT}
                                                                                    \item Gefahr an lokale Verhärtung der WEZ wegen niedrige Wärmezufuhr \cite{\ship, \tric}
                                                                            \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                        &%Kosten
                                                                                    3
                                                                            &%Faktor

                                                                            \\[18pt]
    \midrule%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                                                                                                          
        \textbf{Spannungs\-armglühen} &%Wirkung
                                                                                    Verbesserung der Nahtgeometrie
                                                                            &%Vorteil\
                                                                             \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item ausführliche Beschreibung und Charakterisierung \cite{\ship}
                                                                                \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                            &%Nachteil
                                                                             \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item zweifelhafter Vorteil \cite{\ship, nitschke-pagel_wirkungsweise_2008}
                                                                                    \item 
                                                                            \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                        &%Kosten
                                                                                ---
                                                                            &%Faktor
                                                                                    1,3 - 1,8
                                                                            \\[18pt]
    \midrule%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \textbf{Kugel- bzw. Sandstrahlen} &%Wirkung
                                                                                    Verbesserung der Nahtgeometrie
                                                                            &%Vorteil
                                                                             \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item   
                                                                            \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                            &%Nachteil
                                                                             \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item   
                                                                            \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                        &%Kosten
                                                                                    1,5
                                                                            &%Faktor

                                                                            \\[18pt]
    \midrule%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \textbf{konventionelles Hämmern} &%Wirkung
                                                                                    Verbesserung der Nahtgeometrie
                                                                            &%Vorteil
                                                                             \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item   
                                                                            \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                            &%Nachteil
                                                                              \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item Niedrige Frequenzen   \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005, \IIWPWT, \ship, \lqmart}
                                                                                    \item hohe Geräusch- und Vibrationsbelastung \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005, \IIWPWT, \ship, \lqmart}
                                                                                    \item hohe Reproduzierbarkeit nicht gewährleistet \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005}
                                                                                \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                        &%Kosten
                                                                                    1
                                                                            &%Faktor
                                                                                    1,3 - 1,8
                                                                            \\[18pt]
    \midrule%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \textbf{\hfh} &%Wirkung
                                                                                    Verbesserung der Nahtgeometrie
                                                                            &%Vorteil
                                                                              \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item leichte Bedienbarkeit \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005, \IIWPWT, \ship, \lqmart}
                                                                                    \item geringe Geräusch- und Vibrationsbelastung \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005, \IIWPWT, \ship, \lqmart}
                                                                                    \item an den Werkstoff anpassungsfähig \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005}
                                                                                    \item hohe Reproduzierbarkeit \cite{\lqmart, kuhlmann_erhohung_2005, \ship}
                                                                                \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                            &%Nachteil
                                                                             \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item   
                                                                            \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                        &%Kosten
                                                                                    ---
                                                                            &%Faktor
                                                                                    1,3 - 1,8
                                                                            \\[18pt]
                                                                                \midrule%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \textbf{\hfh} &%Wirkung
                                                                                    Verbesserung der Nahtgeometrie
                                                                            &%Vorteil
                                                                              \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item leichte Bedienbarkeit \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005, \IIWPWT, \ship, \lqmart}
                                                                                    \item geringe Geräusch- und Vibrationsbelastung \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005, \IIWPWT, \ship, \lqmart}
                                                                                    \item an den Werkstoff anpassungsfähig \cite{kuhlmann_erhohung_2005}
                                                                                    \item hohe Reproduzierbarkeit \cite{\lqmart, kuhlmann_erhohung_2005, \ship}
                                                                                \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                            &%Nachteil
                                                                             \begin{minipage}{56mm}
                                                                                \begin{itemizenon}  
                                                                                    \item   
                                                                            \end{itemizenon}    
                                                                                \end{minipage}
                                                                        &%Kosten
                                                                                    ---
                                                                            &%Faktor
                                                                                    1,3 - 1,8
                                                                            \\[18pt]
    \bottomrule%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{tabularx}


\end{small}

\end{landscape}
```

EDIT :

I use a document class given from the institution for which I am writing this document. With the document class report or article, I get the same problem with the orientation of the table.

Here are some packages that I use (I only give them that are useful for the table because I use many packages)

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

Here the definition of itemizenon:

```
\newenvironment{itemizenon}{
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt]
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
}{\end{itemize}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which document class do you use? Which packages do you load? How (or where) is the `itemizenon` environment defined?

Comment: Sorry for the missing information. I use a document class given from the institution for which I am writing this document. With the document class report or article, I habe the same problem with the orientation of the table.

I write the packages I use and the definition of itemizenon in my first message.

Comment: Can you combine your fragments into an example we can compile using `article`, say. I don't really understand what the problem is or what the relation is to the picture. `tabularx` doesn't split across pages, so how do you end up with tabular material on two pages? Are these different tables? Why are you using a tabular for all these `itemize` environments?

Comment: We need code we can compile to produce the picture shown and a clear description of what you want to be different about the result.